# PL/SQL Loop to Revoke Privileges

Tags: sql, loops, plsql, procedure

I need to create a procedure that does the following:

1. Revoke system privileges granted directly to the user. (Table: dba_sys_privs)
2. Revoke object privileges granted directly to the user. (Table: dba_tab_privs)
3. It revokes roles granted directly to the user. (Table: dba_role_privs)

It has to loop through the tables and remove all of them for a user. So far I have #1 and #3 working. But I need to add #2, and I can't seem to figure out how to do it. This is my code for #2, and I keep getting an error:

```
//REVOKING OBJECT PRIVILEGES
CREATE or REPLACE PROCEDURE deactivate_user 
    (p_username IN VARCHAR2) AS
l_username VARCHAR2(30) := UPPER(p_username);
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN (SELECT * FROM dba_tab_privs WHERE GRANTEE = p_username)
    LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON TABLE '||rec.owner||'.'||rec.table_name||' FROM '||rec.grantee; 
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

When I try to execute the code: SQL> exec deactivate_user('BLAKE'), I get this error:
ERROR: at line 1:
ORA-06550: table or view does not exist
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DEACTIVATE_USER", line 7

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a known error.

Comment: I've edited my question. Please check the new addition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct command for table privileges is either:

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES FROM ...
```

or:

```
REVOKE READ FROM ...
```

And it's even better to add the TABLE keyword as well.

So the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statement should be either:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON TABLE ' || rec.owner || '.' || rec.table_name ||' FROM '|| rec.grantee;
```

or:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'REVOKE ' || rec.privilege || ' ON TABLE ' || rec.owner || '.' || rec.table_name ||' FROM '|| rec.grantee;
```

**Update**

The most important thing was missing in my first answer: the table owner.

Comment: I'm still getting the "invalid table name" for some reason :S Thanks so much for all your help btw!

Comment: That's strange. Please print the full statement (DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE instead of EXECUTE IMMEDIATE) and add it to your question.

Comment: Kk, so when I do this:
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON TABLE '||rec.owner||'.'||rec.table_name||' FROM '||rec.grantee); It executes without the error, however, the rows are not removed from the table!

Comment: It's not supposed to change anything. It should write the statements to standard output, a DBMS_OUTPUT window etc. depending on the tool you use to execute the procedure. Depending on your tool, you might need to activate the output first.

Comment: Interesting, it is printing the correct thing...just it's not commiting I guess. But I think i got this. Thanks so much for your help!